# What is 'Sequence' on the Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-calendar-api, sequence

I'm using the Google Calendar API and I need to understand when the start date of an event has been updated, I want to do this without having to store the original event. Currently the only metadata I can see which might give me this capability is the '[Sequence](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events?hl=en)' as I noticed that whenever I updated the start date of the event the sequence would increment, and it doesn't increment when I tried changing a few other fields. Can anybody confirm whether the sequence only increments when the start date changes?

Comment: This blog has an amazing explanation on the same: https://icalevents.com/4437-correct-handling-of-uid-recurrence-id-sequence/